# How do I detect if a sprite is touching another sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I determine if a sprite (Sprite1) if on top of (Sprite2)
I need this to switch levels when you touch another sprite with your sprite.
I tried:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    //code to run
}
```

But this made it so that everything it touched ran the code. :(

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should attach the script that contains `oncollisioneneter` to your sprite1 game object for example and in your sprite 2 game object add a tag like sp2 or whatever you want , then in your script when collision happens you check if the object that sprite one collided with is sprite 2 you check it with tag property of sprite 2 like this

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "sp2")
        {
          //put your change levelcode here
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your halfway there. Right now you are running the code whenever the sprite collides with another 2D collider. What you then need to do is determine if that collider is the one attached to the particular sprite we want to trigger the code.

Tag the object containing your level exit, and check for the tag when you get a hit.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "levelExit")
    {
        Debug.Log("next level");
    }
}
```

Comment: This gave 'UnityEngine.Collision2D' does not contain definition for 'tag'

Comment: My apologies, did a quick Google and Collision2D does not inherit tag (I always do this with 3D, where you can use Collider.tag). It does, however, have a link to the game object, which does have the tag.

    other.gameObject.tag == "levelExit"